# Accessing outer function parameters in nested functions giving weird behavior?

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, python-decorators

I have the following piece of code, it works and gives the correct output:

```
def msg_before(msg=None):
    def actual_decorator(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            print(msg if msg is not None else "was none")  # original
            result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            return result
        return wrapper
    return actual_decorator


@msg_before("this comes before")
def test_func():
    print("test")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_func()
```

> output:
>
> ```
> this comes before
> test
> ```

But when I change the `wrapper` function like this:

```
def msg_before(msg=None):
    def actual_decorator(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            msg = msg if msg is not None else "was none"  # changed
            print(msg)                                    # changed
            result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            return result
        return wrapper
    return actual_decorator
```

I get the following error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:/Users/ruohola/Desktop/test.py", line 33, in <module>
>     test_func()
>   File "C:/Users/ruohola/Desktop/test.py", line 19, in wrapper
>     msg = msg if msg is not None else "was none"  # changed
> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'msg' referenced before assignment
> ```

To me both of the codes seem identical, and I just don't understand where the error comes from and why it doesn't occur in the first code?

Comment: You are referencing a variable even before its assignment!

Comment: @DirtyBit how come I can access its value in the `print()` then in the first example?

Comment: The presence or absence of `msg =`, i.e. an *assignment to the variable*, makes all the difference.